# Google Security Checkup Gmail Settings

Tags: gmail, privacy, google-account

Today, Google suggested running a security checkup. While almost everything was clear and helpful, one section *Check your Gmail settings* was unclear. It says:
"Make sure that your Gmail settings are up to date and remove settings that are not familiar to you.", and as a suggestion, it gives: `Remove display name: <My full name>`.

What is the significance of that? Where will the name be removed from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *believe* that's the name that gets sent as part of your email address when you send messages, ergo:

```
John Doe <snipehunter334@gmail.com>
```

(I think also exposes your name when someone uses Gmail to send you a message as well.)

If your email address isn't your name (mine is) and you want to keep some anonymity, you might want to change that.

You can also change that setting directly in Gmail by:

1. (Gear) > Settings
2. Accounts and Import
3. Send mail as > edit info
   [image: edit name information screen shot]

Comment: That is precisely what it does. Try sending an email to yourself after applying the setting and you can see the absence of the name from the header data.